# exec returns permission denied when executed through browser

Tags: php, apache, permissions, user-permissions, lynx

```
lynx -cmd_script=TMP_FILES/1077/addressfinderfile1427734110 http://cti.voa.gov.uk/cti/InitS.asp
```

The above shown is the command which is working perfect while executing through terminal. But when we put it in a php file and execute, it shows permission denied error.
I set 777 permission for that particular file and folder. No luck.
Changed ownership to apache(the default web server user). no luck.
Tried executing script via terminal(php info.php), worked perfect.
but when executing through browser, it fails by saying permission denied.

Comment: so what's in this script?

Comment: it will save the contents of the lynx browser to a file.

Comment: Does webserver user have permission to execute `lynx` binary? Another thing is that `lynx` may try to create some temporary file or read some config.

Comment: it is working when we execute the command directly from terminal. but not via php exec() function.